# Product database schema redesign

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I designed my store to sell custom machined parts. Currently my products are actually a package of products (options). Schema looks like this:

```
types
    id, name

products
    id, type_id, name

optiontypes
    id, name

options
    id, type_id, name

product_option
    id, product_id, option_id

carts
    id, session, product_id

cart_option
    id, cart_id, option_id

orders
    id, name

order_option
    id, order_id, option_id
```

My problem is Im having repeat customers that have bought packages and now want to buy single items for replacements. I was thinking merge optiontypes into types, and options into products, but then how would I figure out whats a packaged product or a single product?

#### Edit

After reading about BOM - Modular bill of materials from pst's comment this what Im looking to do:

```
------------------------------------

ORDER: 1001

package1
    module1
        component1
        component2
    module2
        component3
        component4
        component5

------------------------------------

ORDER: 1002

component1
component5

------------------------------------

ORDER: 1003

package2
    module1
        component1
    module2
        component3

------------------------------------
```

How would I go about finding a solution to have the best of both?

Comment: can you just have a package with a single product in it?

Comment: It might be worth looking into BOMs - then any "level" of a BOM (that was sellable) could be added to a cart. Also, this was very confusing to read - try to avoid overloading terms except if there is a warranted reason for the consistency/use.

Comment: I did some reading about BOMs and found Modular BOMs, could you check my edit?

Comment: There's not enough information here to clearly understand what you mean by _module_. For instance, in Order 1001 **module1** contains _component1_ and _component2_ - however in order 1003 **module1** only contains _component1_. **module2** is similarly inconsistent.

If a module does not consistently contain the same components isn't it just a different package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so a *package* contains one or more *parts*.  Customers can place an *order* for one or more *packages* and/or one or more *parts*. Since I don't know what an option might be I more or less merged it in with *part_type* so maybe you have an **Aluminum** part type as well as a **Pre-Drilled Aluminum** part type.

Your *order* keeps track of what *packages* were ordered as well as what separate *parts* were ordered. If I'm understanding you correctly, there's no physical difference between a part that is sold as a component of a package or a part that was sold by itself - you just need to be able to track how it was purchased. Setting things up like this would let you keep track of that.

```
packages
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     text // This package contains all the parts you need to build SuperMegaWidget!

packages_parts
    id              unsigned int(P)
    package_id      unsigned int(F packages.id)
    part_id         unsigned int(F parts.id)

part_types
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(50) // Aluminum, Brass, whatever, etc.

parts
    id              unsigned int(P)
    part_type_id    unsigned int(F part_types.id)
    name            varchar(50) // Widget A, Widget B, etc.

orders
    id              unsigned int(P)
    ... lots of other information in here

orders_packages
    id              unsigned int(P)
    order_id        unsigned int(F orders.id)
    package_id      unsigned int(F packages.id)

orders_parts
    id              unsigned int(P)
    order_id        unsigned int(F order.id)
    part_id         unsigned int(F parts.id)
```